# how does dunce cap has simplicial structure

Tags: algebraic-topology

Dunce cap is a example of space which is contractible but not collapsible, but collapsibility is only defined for simplicial complexes. Can anyone explain how does dunce hat has simplicial structure?

Comment: actually I think it's normally called the 'dunce hat'.

Comment: Yes, we can also call this by dunce hat.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675145/simplicial-complexes-triangulation-general-question